# NSString isEqualToString won't return true, and unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I have a string `dummyString` that needs to be compared to 100. Here's my code

```
  dummyString = [prefs objectForKey:@"displaySize"];
[self setDisplaySize:dummyString];
NSLog(@"Getting ready to set display controller with value %@", dummyString);


NSLog(@"Tried 1");
if ([dummyString isEqual: @"5"]) {
    NSLog(@"Loaded preferences, display Small");
    displayChanged.selectedSegment = 0;}

NSLog(@"Tried 2");
if ([dummyString isEqual: @"40"]){
    NSLog(@"Loaded preferences, display is Med!");
        displayChanged.selectedSegment = 1;}

NSLog(@"Tried 3");
if ([dummyString isEqualToString:@"100"]){
    NSLog(@"Loaded preferences, display LARGE");
    displayChanged.selectedSegment = 2;}

NSLog(@"Completed trying to get display controller with value %@", dummyString);
```

Here's the NSLog

```
2013-03-26 17:22:49.101 CopyBot[1011:303] Getting ready to set display controller with value 100
 2013-03-26 17:22:49.102 CopyBot[1011:303] Tried 1
 2013-03-26 17:22:49.102 CopyBot[1011:303] Tried 2
 2013-03-26 17:22:49.102 CopyBot[1011:303] Tried 3
 2013-03-26 17:22:49.103 CopyBot[1011:303] -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x64c7
 2013-03-26 17:22:49.103 CopyBot[1011:303] -[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x64c7
```

I've tried a few variations of declaring different strings, but can't seem to ever get it to enter the 'if' statement for any comparison of isEqual or isEqualToString. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [prefs objectForKey:@"displaySize"] is returning a NSNumber.

Comment: How would you assume they're working? The NSLog output inside each if() statement never is called. @AndrewMadsen

Comment: It's never called because the exception is thrown when you call isEqualToString: .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your error your `dummyString` is not `NSString` indeed it is `NSNumber`.

You can convert your string `@"5"` to `NSNumber` and then compare :

```
BOOL equal=[dummyString isEqualToNumber:@([@"5" integerValue])];
```

Or. convert dummystring value to string and then compare:

```
BOOL equal=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[dummyString integerValue]] isEqualToString:@"5"];
```

Comment: @newtoxcode: As the name `dummyString` suggests it is string that is where most of us will rub our head. But you have a method called `[dummyString class]` which will return you its class type. Simply log this and you can be sure whether it is string or array or number.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the error message `[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector...` the problem is that `__NSCFNumber` doesn't have an `isEqualToString` method.

`__NSCFNumber` is how Cocoa represents most `NSNumber`s at runtime.

So your problem is that dummyString isn't a string at all, it's an `NSNumber`

Comment: @newtoxcode: Just because the variable is of type NSString doesn't mean the object is. `[prefs objectforKey:@"startup"]` is obviously an NSNumber.

Comment: @newtoxcode Just because you're storing it in a box that says "string" on the outside, doesn't mean it actually contains a string. Objective-C is often more than happy to store a value in a mistyped variable. To really check something is the type you're expecting, use `isKindOfClass:` i.e. `[dummyString isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]` will return false.

Comment: @newtoxcode As a simpler example, `NSString * notAString = (id)[NSNumber numberWithInt:4]`. The compiler is perfectly happy to compile this for you, but if you try to perform string operations on it, your program will crash.